# How to proceed in the proof of this statement.

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I'm reading the proof of "Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups" in Herstein Abstract Algebra, and I've found this statement in the proof that I don't see very clear.

Let $A$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. And suppose $b\in G$ and the order of $b$ is prime $p$, and $b$ is not in $A$. Then $A \cap (b)=(e)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A\cap(b)$ is a subgroup of $(b)$. Since $b$ has prime order, the only subgroups of $(b)$ are $(e)$ and $(b)$ (by Lagrange's theorem).

If $A\cap(b)=(b)$ we have $(b)\subseteq A$, so $b\in A$. Since, by assumption, $b\notin A$, we must have $A\cap(b)=(e)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in A\cap (b)$ then $x=b^n$ for some $n$. If the order of $b$ is $p$ and $x\ne e$ then we can take $0<n<p$. Since $p$ is prime there exists $m$ so that $b^{nm}=b$; hence $b\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that exists $0<k<p$ such that $b^k\in A\to b^{km}\in A \forall m\in\mathbb{Z} *$.

Now, $p$ is prime, $(k,p)=1\to ak+cp=1$ for any $a,c$.

If we put $m=a$ in $*$, obtain that $b^{ka}=b^{1-bp}=b.(b^p)^{-b}=b\in A$, an absurd.